# Form field validator

Tags: 8, forms

Is there a way to validate fields individually like you would've done for the file upload (Eg: file_validate_extension etc)? I want to do something like this:

```
$form["field_name"] = array(
  "#type" => "textfield",
  ...
  "#field_validate" = array("field_validate_numeric") // or "field_validate_email" or "field_validate_url" etc
);
```

I know there are new html5 field types but I want to be able to validate textfields.

Also, I need this because I might not know the actual tree structure or field parents and I want to validate the field no matter how the form looks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a callback, so that it will work whereever you use it in the form tree:

Add this to your form element:

```
'#element_validate' => [[get_class($this), 'validateNumber']],
```

And put the callback in the form class:

```
public static function validateNumber(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    $value = $element['#value'];
    if ($value === '') {
      return;
    }

    $name = empty($element['#title']) ? $element['#parents'][0] : $element['#title'];

    // Ensure the input is numeric.
    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
      $form_state->setError($element, t('%name must be a number.', array('%name' => $name)));
      return;
    }
}
```

(for the callback I've used some of the code from the html5 number element)

Answer (score 3):

The properties that are common to all the form fields are listed in [`FormElement`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement/8.2.x). Those include also `#element_validate`, which is described as the following.

> **#element_validate**: (array) Array of callables or function names, which are called to validate the input. Arguments: `$element`, `$form_state`, `$form`.

The code you are showing works when:

- You replace `#field_validate` with `#element_validate`
- You fix the syntax error (i.e. replace `= array(` with `=> array(`)
- You use a validation handler that exists in Drupal 8 (Drupal 8 doesn't have any `field_validate_numeric()` function)